# How to Analyze Categorical Data in a Repeated Measures Design?

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, experiment-design

First post. I've read through similar posts and no one's quite answered it already, so I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring. Here goes:

I have a repeated-measures design planned proposes to ask a number of subjects to answer a series of questions after reading five different clinical case histories. The group of questions is the same after each case history. Some of the data gathered from the questions is categorical: there are two multiple-choice questions about diagnosis and treatment ("pick the most appropriate diagnosis / intervention from the following list"). Each multiple-choice question has five possible answers.

How can I analyze this data to see if there is an association between a given case history (1 through 5) and a given diagnosis / intervention? Or to see if case history predicts a given diagnosis or intervention?

Since it's a repeated-measures design, the data will not be independent. Do I have any options?